# Navigate relative with Angular 2 Router (Version 3)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

How to navigate relative from `/questions/123/step1` to `/questions/123/step2` within a component using `Router` without string concatenation and specifying `/questions/123/`?

I've added an own answer below. Please feel free to suggest a better answer. ;-) I guess there are better approaches.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

After doing some more research I came across with

```js
this.router.createUrlTree(['../step2'], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});
```

and

```js
this.router.navigate(['../step2'], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});
```

First approach ([Router.createUrlTree API](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#createUrlTree-anchor)) did not work for me, i.e. nothing happened. Second approach ([Router.navigate API](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#navigate-anchor)) works.

**Update 2016-10-12**

There is another stackoverflow question as well:

- [How do I navigate to a sibling route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38634237/how-do-i-navigate-to-a-sibling-route)

**Update 2016-10-24**

Documentation:

- [Routing & Navigation (Relative Navigation)](https://angular.io/guide/router#relative-navigation)

**Update 2019-03-08**

It seems that there were changes in Angular 7.1. There is an answer in another post how to solve it with Angular 7.1. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/38634440/42659.

Comment: according to my test it should be `this.router.navigate(['step2'], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});` without ../ before path.

Comment: @XinMeng the ../ is specific to this example, here the goal is trying to go up one level, and then add step2.  so for example `/parent/child` would become `/parent/step2` whereas in your example it becomes `/parent/child/step2`.  Your example is valid code as well, but for the specific question asked the answer is correct.

Comment: One gotcha I had was the ActivatedRoute doesn't know about the current route if the class you're injecting it into has `@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})`.

Answer (score 25):

First, inject router & ActivatedRoute on constructor

```
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,private router:Router) { }
```

then use to Click Event:

```
onEditClick(){
        this.router.navigate(['edit'],{relativeTo:this.route});
```

You navigate to the expected page.In my scenario, I wanted to go recipe /1 to edit the recipe.
http://localhost:4200/recipes/1/edit

Answer (score 5):

> **Note:** the routes are case sensitive so make sure you match the casing across

This worked for me for Angular 8:
From the parent component / page, to navigate to the sub page using typescript:

```
this.router.navigate(['subPage'], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

My router in the parent's module looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MyPage,
    children: [
      { path: 'subPage', component: subPageComponent}
    ]
  }
];
```

And on the parent's html page use the following to navigate using a link:

```
<a [routerLink]="'subPage'">Sub Page Link</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use below,

Assumption is `questions` is loaded into your primary `router-outlet`

```
  this.router.navigate([
      '/',
      { 
        outlets: {
          primary: [
              // below may be replaced with different variables
              'questions',
              '123',  
              'step2'
          ]
        }
      }
  ])
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks. But I would like to avoid to write the complete route path.