# Navigate using url and ../ in Angular 5

Tags: angular, navigation, router

I have this in my html:

```
(click)="openAlbum($event, album.post_id)"
```

And in my ts:

```
 openAlbum(event, post_id) {
            this.router.navigate(['../my-albums/' + post_id]);
    }
```

I'm standing now in this url: `http://localhost:4200/profile/username/photos`

I expected the url become: `http://localhost:4200/profile/username/my-albums`

But the result: `http://localhost:4200/my-albums`

Comment: why don't you give full url in router navigate? like `this.router.navigate(['profile/username/my-albums/' + post_id]);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigate relative with Angular 2 Router (Version 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39124906/navigate-relative-with-angular-2-router-version-3)

Answer (score 0):

After the link parameters array, add an object with a relativeTo property set to the ActivatedRoute. The router then calculates the target URL based on the active route's location. You can try like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['../my-albums/' + post_id], { relativeTo: this.route });
```