# Angular router: Skipping loading parent route if routerLink is clicked from a nested route

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have a page with tabs, each tab is loaded according to a route:

```
    <div class="tabs-container">
        <div class="tab-button" [routerLink]="'history'" [routerLinkActive]="'selected'">
            <span class="pi pi-calendar"></span>
            <span class="text">History</span>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-button" [routerLink]="'status'" [routerLinkActive]="'selected'">
            <span class="pi pi-chart-line"></span>
            <span class="text">Status</span>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-button" [routerLink]="'settings'" [routerLinkActive]="'selected'">
            <span class="pi pi-cog"></span>
            <span class="text">Settings</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If inside the "status" tab (route is `/status`), and the "settings" tab button is clicked, the route changes to `/settings` and the settings tab is loaded.
Inside the settings tab (route = `/settings`), a nested route can be loaded, such as `/settings/add`.

When inside a nested route under the settings tab, for ex. `/settings/add`, how do I prevent going back and loading `/settings` if the "settings" tab button is clicked?

Comment: Relative to this.route? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39124906/navigate-relative-with-angular-2-router-version-3