# Router navigate to child route - Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-router, angular-routerlink

I've defined my routes like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
    { path: 'faq', loadChildren: './faq/faq.module#FaqPageModule' },
    { path: 'terms', loadChildren: './terms/terms.module#TermsPageModule' }
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

and like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/(list:list)',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: 'list',
        outlet: 'list',
        component: ListPage
      },
      {
        path: 'profile',
        outlet: 'profile',
        component: ProfilePage,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/(list:list)',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

I am interested how I can navigate to ListPage or ProfilePage using router `.navigate()` method in component or `routerLink` in some html element.

I tried something like this

```
this.router.navigate(['tabs/profile']);
```

or

```
this.router.navigate(['profile']);
```

or

```
this.router.navigate(['tabs(profile:profile)']);
```

and got this error :

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: ''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution by adding profile path below '' and 'tabs' path:

```
  {
    path: 'profile',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/(profile:profile)',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
```

Now I am able to navigate to profile with

```
  this.router.navigate(['profile']);
```

I forgot to add this path in tabs.router.module.ts. Because of that I was getting mentioned error

Answer (score 34):

Try:

```
this.router.navigate(['child component path'], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});
```

This solved my problem.
Happy coding :)

Comment: don't forget to add `import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';`

Answer (score 20):

```js
this.router.navigate(['/list'], {relativeTo: this.route});      //absolute
this.router.navigate(['./list'], {relativeTo: this.route});     //child
this.router.navigate(['../list'], {relativeTo: this.route});    //sibling
this.router.navigate(['../../list'], {relativeTo: this.route}); //parent
this.router.navigate(['tabs/list'], {relativeTo: this.route});
this.router.navigate(['/tabs/list'], {relativeTo: this.route});
```

You'll find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38808116/11135174) more information

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In addition to the answer you've provided, please consider providing a brief explanation of why and how this fixes the issue.

Comment: Not useful. Consider adding details on what each option does.

Comment: Even tho this is lacking a bit of text, it **did** help. The comments are enough to get the point.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to navigate to the `list` route you need to make the angular know that its a child route of `tabs`

`this.router.navigate(['/tabs/list']);` or `this.router.navigate(['tabs','list']);`

In router navigate you need to pass routes as an array of `string` so now the angular will find for the parent `tabs` and checks the child route if it is nothing it will navigate to `pathMatch: 'full'` if not it will navigate to the specific child route

In `routerLink` you can use the same array to match the route

Thanks, Happy coding !!

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong but same error is displayed for both options. "Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tabs'"

Comment: You are using lazy loading right - when you try to navigate to `TabsPageModule` the route will be empty and try to find the path so i have doubt here - `redirectTo: '/tabs/(offers:offers)'` what does this meant to be because i don't see any route with name `offers` here the code get confused

Comment: just edited code, but when I change to redirectTo: '/tabs/(list:list)' this is not working

Comment: Just make it as `/tabs/list` this will render `ListPage` component  the initial navigation will work or use `/tabs` this will render the `TabsPage` component  - Finally i don't think the `children` routes require a `pathMatch` remove that and check once

Comment: In the children array for the `path=" "` bind the component `ListPage` don't redirect to the same `list` route remove `redirect` and remove `pathMatch` and add `component` so now if it's only 'tabs' will render both `TabsPage` and `ListPage`  component when the route is `tabs` hope this will work -  and in your parent redirect just mention the route name as 'tabs' it will automatically pick that route

Answer (score 2):

It depends on from which component you wish to navigate from.

From Tabs to ListPage:

```
this.router.navigate(['/list'], {relativeTo: this.route});
```

If you're navigating from ProfilePage to ListPage (which are siblings) then, you need to use this:

```
this.router.navigate(['../list'], {relativeTo: this.route});
```

In the above code, route is the ActivatedRoute object and so it will enable relative navigation from current route. You can inject it in the constructor like this:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute)
```

I was also facing the same problem once and tried everything but nothing worked. In the end, Visual Studio Code's Intellisense helped me with this. Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Mention `outlets` in the `routerLink` while navigating to particular outlet.

```
[routerLink]="['tabs/profile', {outlets: {'profile': ['profile'], 'list': ['none']}}]"
```

which will eventually generates below route

```
http://localhost:4200/tabs/profile/(profile:profile//list:none)
```