# router.navigate not working for named router outlet

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular7

I am using a named router outlet in Angular7 and trying to redirect from the component using router.navigate function. But it throws this error

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'additem'
```

Here is my code:

```
<button mat-button (click)="AddItem()">Add Item</button>
<button mat-button (click)="BookItem()">Book Item</button>

<a mat-button [routerLink]="[{ outlets: {mainOutlet: 'additem'}}]">Add item</a>
<a mat-button [routerLink]="[{ outlets: {mainOutlet: 'bookitem'}}]">Book item</a>

<router-outlet name='mainOutlet'></router-outlet>
```

The links with [routerLink] work but the buttons don't.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-topnav',
  templateUrl: './topnav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./topnav.component.css']
})
export class TopnavComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  AddItem(){
    this.router.navigate(['additem']);
  }

  BookItem(){
    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: {mainOutlet: 'bookitem'}}]);
  }
}
```

I've also tried:

```
this.router.navigate(['additem', { outlets: {mainOutlet: 'additem'}}]);
```

app-routing-module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { IndexComponent } from './index/index.component';
import { AdditemComponent } from './additem/additem.component';
import { BookitemComponent } from './bookitem/bookitem.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: IndexComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: "home", 
    component: HomeComponent ,
    children: [
      { path: 'additem', component: AdditemComponent, outlet: "mainOutlet" },
      { path: 'bookitem', component: BookitemComponent, outlet: "mainOutlet" }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
export const routingComponents = [IndexComponent, HomeComponent, AdditemComponent, BookitemComponent];
```

I am unable to find out the issue here. I'd really appreciate any help in this.

Comment: Bro did you find the solution for this problem?

Comment: Yes after a lot research finally I did. The path in navigate method is relative. So, it depends on which component we're redirecting from. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56509622/5624398