# Why my router navigate function doesn't work in angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, angular8, router

I'm trying to redirect to another component like this:

**HomeComponent**

```
  checkUrl(reference) {   
    if (reference != this.ref) {
      this.router.navigate(['/еrror']);
    }
  }
```

here is my router module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DefaultComponent },
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      { path: ':dlr/:id/:ref', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'error', component: ErrorPageComponent },
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }

];
```

right now I'm in the *HomeComponent* and want to go to the error page.

**this.router.navigate(['/еrror'])** this leads me to the *DefaultComponent*

Comment: try `this.router.navigate(['еrror']);`

Comment: already tried this way and the result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 this.router.navigate(['/error'], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute });
```

adding **relativeTo** it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Adding details to a previously deleted answer -

As it is a child to child navigation, you can try adding `relativeTo: this.activatedRoute` tag. You can find more about its syntax and usage here [relativeTo](https://angular.io/guide/router#specifying-a-relative-route) in the documentation. This is basically similar to '../' type of notations that we use for navigation in general while trying to specify the path of a file.

Therefore, you can try something like this - `this.router.navigate(['/еrror'], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});`.

Also, one thing to note here is if you will use ['еrror'] instead of this ['/error'], the navigation can be different. If for example, you are currently here - `parent/abc/c1` (where c1 is a child component) and you use `['error']` (where 'error' is the child component of the same parent as c1), the URI will become `parent/abc/c1/error` whereas if you will use `['/error']`, you will be first moved one level up `parent/abc/` and then the other child will be added - `parent/abc/error`.

There are a few other approaches as well described here - [RouterNavigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53208219/router-navigate-to-child-route-angular-6) along with the one that I described above, have a look at it.
Hope this helps.