# Angular navigate to a sibling route?

Tags: angular

How do I navigate from `/login` path to `/monitor` path using `this.router.navigate`?
Similar question but doesn't work for me: [How do I navigate to a sibling route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38634237/how-do-i-navigate-to-a-sibling-route/38808116#38808116) Thanks!

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', redirectTo: 'monitor', pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'monitor',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '', redirectTo: 'dell', pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'lenovo', component: lenovoMonitorComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'dell', component: dellMonitorComponent
      },
    ]
  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, data: { title: 'Login' }, }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In html you would use routerLink as an relative url, e.g: `<a routerLink="/bikes" routerLinkActive="active">Bikes</a>` but in typescript you would need to add the url in navigate as a string enclosed by brackets.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-attribute',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.goToPlaces();
  }

  goToPlaces(){
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/bikes'])
    }, 5000)
  }
}
```

Here is an working example for you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-navigation-example-zivqnx?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: any specific reason to delaying it by 5 sec.

Comment: No reason to delay. Just to showcase, that it works after loading stackblitz demo. It works just as well without the setTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

In your case after successful login, you can use the below code to navigate to the /monitor

```
this.router.navigate(['/monitor']);
```

Answer (score -1):

Turns out it is not a routing problem. The answer here [How do I navigate to a sibling route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38634237/how-do-i-navigate-to-a-sibling-route/38808116#38808116) should work.