# Angular Nested Child Routing

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-ui-router

I am learning use of multiple router-outlet.

While using **navigateBy** function of router, i am not able to view my child route and getting error. But if i access it via **routerLink** in html i get the desired output.

So in below code, navigation to songs is working , but navigation to films is not.

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: 'bollywood',
    component: BollywoodComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'films',
        component: FilmsComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'songs',
        component: SongsComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: 'hollywood',
    component: HollywoodComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'tollywood',
    component: TollywoodComponent
  },
];
```

App Component html

```
<button class="f-margin-16" (click)="navigateToBollywoodSection()"> Bollywood </button>
<button class="f-margin-16"  (click)="navigateToHollywoodSection()"> Hollywood </button>
<button class="f-margin-16" [routerLink]="['tollywood']" > Tollywood </button>

<br>
Router outlet starts now

<router-outlet> </router-outlet>
```

Bollywood Component html

```
<button (click)="navigateToFilms()"> Films </button>
<button [routerLink]="['songs']"> Songs </button>

<router-outlet> </router-outlet>
```

```
  navigateToFilms() {
    this.router.navigate(['/films']);
  }
```

StackBitz Link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1nzkus?file=src/app/bollywood/bollywood.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `router.navigate`, you can pass `relativeTo` as the second param.

```
navigateToFilms() {
    this.router.navigate(['films'], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute} );
}
```

This way navigation will happen relative to the current route.
In the constructor you can add the `ActivatedRoute` dependency.

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

If you use `<button [routerLink]="['songs']"> Songs </button>`, the navigation by default happens relative to the current route.

Comment: This works, but you need to use `this.router.navigate(['films']` instead of `this.router.navigate(['/films']`

Comment: Okay I was not aware about relativeTo thanks.

Comment: Yes it was a mistake. Thanks @MikeS. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this

this.router.navigate(['bollywood/films']);

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained why you need to pass the full path from the root url, while passing only the segment to the `routerLink` inside of the template works.

Comment: The navigate() method requires a starting point (i.e., the relativeTo parameter). If none is provided, the navigation is absolute:

You can refer to a detailed explanation in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38634237/how-do-i-navigate-to-a-sibling-route/38808116#38808116

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a navigation route then you can use this code.
because without a specific parent route you can't access child routing.

```
this.router.navigate(['/bollywood/films']);
```